# Create a secondary organisation with the same billing account in GCP in Cloudidentity only

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP account with one organisation and a billing account.
In my case only cloud identity can be used (no Google Workspace).

Now I need to create a second organisation (in the same account or different account all ways are fine) but **the billing account must remain the same**.

Any idea how to achieve this ? I found only this but this seems to refer to Google Workspace only:  https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/managing-multiple-orgs#using_multiple_organization_nodes maybe someone has another idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create the new organization and a project, assign the existing Billing Account to the project in the new organization.

I recommend either creating the new organization with an identity from the old organization that has Billing Account Administrator or add an identity from the new organization to the billing account after creating the organization.

Note: billing accounts are linked to projects. It does not matter which organization a project is assigned to. This means an IAM role to the project and the billing account.

Comment: Hi @John the problem is how to create a new organisation node without a new billing account. My understanding is that one organisation is associated to a GCP account and without associating a billing account with the new organisation node how can I create it ?

Comment: @Jean-philippeUlpiano - create a new project without an organization. Link the billing account to the project. Now create an organization with the new project.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, actually as mentionned in my original question, I need to create a second organisation ... this is a requirement from my customer. Any idea how to do so withoutcreating a new billing account ?

Comment: did you follow the steps in my last comment? If yes, what problem did you have?

Comment: Hi @John, actually this does not seem possible:
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#organizations


The link says:
    "It is impossible to create a project that isn't associated with an organization."

Comment: You are misreading the documentation. I create projects with no organization very often. The key item is the **identity** that is creating the project. If your identity is a **managed** identity, then you are already part of an organization. Use an identity that is not **managed**.